# Bug in my preg-match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have a big problem right now with this sample code:

```
preg_match_all("/\[BLOG\=\[(.*)]](.*)\[\/BLOG]/U", $this->soruces , $match_list );
```

and i don't know why its not will working, its print this out to me

```
Array ( [0] => GROUPID=23|CATID=28|SORT=ASE [1] => GROUPID=23|CATID=29|SORT=ASE [2] => GROUPID=23|CATID=30|SORT=ASE )
```

normal its will return [0][0] = original code, [1][0] = found 1 code, and [2][0] = found code 2, but why its not working here? can somebody see what i did wrong?

Comment: What input are you matching the regex against?

Answer (score 1):

try:

`preg_match_all("/\[BLOG\=\[(.*?)\]\](.*?)\[\/BLOG\]/U", $this->soruces , $match_list );`

Comment: Ungreedy modifier *and* ungreedy quantifier?

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. I'm obviously way to tired for this.

Comment: tanks, :) this is one problem the ordre problem is i try to print a wrong var :( tanks for help :D

Answer (score 0):

You could start by escaping the closing square brackets too:

```
#\[BLOG=\[(.*)\]\](.*)\[/BLOG\]#U
```

but we need to see the text you're trying to match to tell more.